# Confluent Replicator Failed to Reconfigure Connectors Task?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have used mirror maker in the past and not Replicator and am getting an error but now sure where to start to debug it.

Here is the error:

```
[2019-08-12 18:04:09,672] ERROR Failed to reconfigure connector's 
tasks, retrying after backoff: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:958) 
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Could not obtain timely topic metadata update from source cluster
    at io.confluent.connect.replicator.TopicMonitorThreadWithZk.assignments(TopicMonitorThreadWithZk.java:138)
    at io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector.taskConfigs(ReplicatorSourceConnector.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker.connectorTaskConfigs(Worker.java:317)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.reconfigureConnector(DistributedHerder.java:997)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.reconfigureConnectorTasksWithRetry(DistributedHerder.java:950)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.startConnector(DistributedHerder.java:914)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder.access$1300(DistributedHerder.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$15.call(DistributedHerder.java:924)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder$15.call(DistributedHerder.java:920)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Are you able to solve this issue?, if so what exactly you did this. am also getting the same error in Confluent Replicator